# Can I use happy.js at the bottom of my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a web project where all JS (mostly jQuery) code is put at the bottom of the page. I have to implement some form validation and I would like to use happy.js (mostly because of its weight), only for some reason this script only works when used, together with jQuery, in the `<head>` tag.

Is there a way so that I can use happy.js and still keep jQuery at the bottom of my page? If not, are there any good alternatives for happy.js?

Comment: please more details or site of this plugin happy.js

Comment: Make sure that you're loading jQuery before happy.js

Comment: any plugin that uses jquery must after the jquery src

Comment: It really is a good practice to let the javascript code in the page footer to provide fluidity. Have you tried changing the order of scripts declaration?

Comment: @Mirko: Sorry, my bad: http://happyjs.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`happy.js` relies on jQuery - it must be loaded *after* it, it's as simple as that. If you wanted to, you could move both jQuery *and* happy.js to be at the bottom of your page.

Curious though - why does it matter to you where you load it? Apart from forcing it to load after your page in older browsers, I fail to see the benefit these days.

Comment: Thanks, @Rudi, I'll try that (again)! Regarding your second question: I like to know the answer too. I was always used to putting my scripts in the `<head>`, but ever since the HTML5 BoilerPlate I've put them at the bottom before `</body>` (their explanation seemed logical).

Comment: Ok, here's what went wrong. Seemed like nothing worked because I made a typo in one of the field ids. Sorry for wasting everyone's time :-( [ bumps head against wall ]